# Hide custom field in woocommerce based on payment method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to hide upload file field in checkout page in woocommerce with paypal payment method  and show it with another payment method ,
when tried to catch witch radio button is "cheacked" now , nothing show in console

my first try

````
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function hidefileinput() {
    let radio = jQuery('input[name=payment_method]:checked');
    console.log(radio);
    const id = jQuery(radio).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    }```

Then I use ```jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {}``` instead ```jQuery(document).ready(function() ```
but nothing happen
any help ??
````